# How to guarantee that rows in mysql show up in an specific way

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the hours worked per day by id, the table has two columns (id, registro):

```
id     registro
1      2017-08-23 08:00:00  -starting working day
1      2017-08-23 12:00:00  -stop for lunching time
2      2017-08-23 12:40:00  
1      2017-08-23 13:00:00  - return from lunching time
1      2017-08-23 17:00:00  - going home
```

Then I copied the idea from : [Get total hours worked in a day mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745182/get-total-hours-worked-in-a-day-mysql) in order to create a column in_out and got this:

```
set @num := 0;
select tab.id, date_format(`registro`,'%d/%m/%Y') as date_,
SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`registro`)*(1-2*`in_out`))/3600 AS `hours_worked`
 from (select id, registro, mod(@num := @num+1,2) as in_out from registro_ponto_v
    where id= 1
    and date_format(registro,"%d-%m-%Y") = '23-08-2017'
    order by registro asc) as tab 
group by tab.id, date_;
```

When I execute on (mysql 14.14 dist 5.7.16 (x86_64) it result 8hs correctly, but when I execute on server version 10.1 on debian 9 for some reason the in_out column doesn't show the same order of rows in subselect... (8hs - 1; 12hs - 0; 13hs -1; 17hs -0)
and so the sum of hours get an value different. Then my point is: there's a way to garantee that the order of rows match to this:

```
id    registro  in_out
1     8hs        1
1     12hs       0
1     13hs       1
1     17hs       0
```

Comment: What if they stay all night?

Comment: The "order by" in the sub query won't be respected by the outer query. Try moving it to the outer query.

Comment: @Strawberry the first entry row would be "in" (1), second would be "out" (0) no matter the time elapsed.

Comment: @Jaydee I suppose that it's happening here, the order by in the sub query is been ignored

Comment: I see. So a 'day' could have more than 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be simpler if you were able to explicitly store 'ins' and 'outs'...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL
, registro DATETIME NOT NULL
,status ENUM('in','out') NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(id,registro)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'2017-08-23 08:00:00','in'),
(1,'2017-08-23 12:00:00','out'),
(2,'2017-08-23 12:40:00','in'),
(1,'2017-08-23 13:00:00','in'),
(1,'2017-08-23 17:00:00','out');

SELECT id
     , DATE(user_in) date
     , SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(user_out,user_in)))) total 
  FROM
     ( SELECT x.id,x.registro user_in,MIN(y.registro) user_out 
         FROM my_table x 
         JOIN my_table y 
           ON y.id = x.id 
          AND y.registro > x.registro 
          AND y.status = 'out' 
        WHERE x.status = 'in' 
        GROUP 
           BY x.id, x.registro
     ) a
 GROUP 
    BY id,date;
+----+------------+----------+
| id | date       | total    |
+----+------------+----------+
|  1 | 2017-08-23 | 08:00:00 |
+----+------------+----------+
```